# How do I see local trends for my (unsupported?) location in Twitter?

Tags: twitter

The options for 'local trends' on Twitter are very limited: I count 20 countries + world wide and 21 cities. Are there more 'official' local trend options or is that it?

Is there a planned timeframe for New Zealand (or other countries) to be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small notice when you use the old Twitter.

> Don't see your location? We're working on it

And from [Support](http://support.twitter.com/articles/101125-about-trending-topics)

> If you don't see your country or city,
>   it means we're not receiving enough
>   tweets from that geographical area to
>   create a quality list. Locations are
>   not manually decided, but displayed
>   dynamically based on tweet volume.

Try TrendsMap for the time being

http://trendsmap.com/local/new+zealand
http://trendsmap.com/?ll=-40.9006_174.886&z=5

[image: New Zealand in TrendsMap]

I am not sure how reliable it is for I am not from NZ.